# Actionscript 3 - Setting multiples of a number equal to a number

Tags: actionscript-3, function, numbers, slider, threshold

I am writing a program in Actionscript 3 that involves a Slider that displays the weeks and months over the course of a year as you slide it to the right in format of "Month 2 Week 3" or "Month 8 Week 2".
I did months like this:
    function monthHandler(){

```
var a:Number = ((Math.ceil(aSlider.value/4))+1);
monthLabel.text = "Month" + String(a);

}
```

However for that same slider (aSlider) I'd like to display weeks, up to 4, for each month. I know that I need to basically set a Number threshold; values 1-4 would display weeks: 1-4, but values 5-8 would also have to display weeks 1-4.

I know I could do this by using a crapton of If() loops but I am relatively new to programming and so I am assuming that there is a more efficient way of doing this, and that I just do not know it. I looked around the web for checking multiples of numbers, and setting number thresholds, but nothing seems to be suited to my problem.

the current code for weeks is:

```
function weekHandler(){
var b:Number = ((Math.ceil(aSlider.value/12))+1);
weekLabel.text = "Week:" + String(b);
}
```

All this does is display 1-4 as I slide my slider across the quarters of the thing. Like I said, I know this doesn't work but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: Look at the docs for the Modulo (%) operator

Comment: I wanted to comment that your use of the 'ceil' function here is possibly incorrect. Since you are adding +1, you should be using .floor() - for instance - .ceil(1.0/4) + 1 = 2; .ceil(3.0/4) + 1 = 2; .. You probably want to return month = 1 for values between 0 to 3. Using floor you would return 1. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your slider had 12-months, 4-weeks per month:

**Months:**

```
var months:int = (int)(dateSlider.value / 4);
```

**Weeks:**

```
var weeks:int = (dateSlider.value % 4) + 1;
```

**Flash Example:**

[image: flash-slider]

If you had a `dateSlider` Flash component:

[image: flash-date-slider]

You could update `dateText` label such as:

```
import fl.events.SliderEvent;

dateSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, sliderChangeHandler);

function sliderChangeHandler(event:SliderEvent):void
{
    dateText.text = "Month: " + (int)(event.value / 4) + " " +
                    "Week: " + ((event.value % 4) + 1);
}
```

**Flex Example:**

[image: month-0] [image: month-6] [image: month-12]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Label text="Month: {(int)(dateSlider.value / 4)} Week: {(dateSlider.value % 4) + 1}" />

    <s:HSlider id="dateSlider"
               maximum="{(13 * 4) - 1}"
               snapInterval="1"
               stepSize="1" />

</s:Application>
```

It should be noted that this interpretation of dates seems rudimentary, as the actual number of weeks per month is 4.34812.

Explicitly calculating date timespans would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I think the code you want is:

```
var a:Number = (Math.ceil(aSlider.value) % 4) +1;
weekLabel.text = "Week" + String(a);
```

a % b = remainder of a divided by b..

You wouldn't need a lot of 'if()' to calculate it otherwise.

You could use `(a - Math.floor(a/b)*b)` <= but don't use that, use `a%b`